# onKeyUp doesn't work in child view

Tags: android, onkeyup, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have this hierarchy of the views:
Activity -> ViewPager -> MyViewGroup

In MyViewGroup (and only there) I override onKeyUp event:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Back");
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

But when I press "Back" key, this override is not called and the app is closed. Why?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the back button finishes the activity. From the android source:

Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.  The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

If you wish to alter this behavior you have to override onBackPressed in your Activity and make it not call super. Then you can implement your own behavior.

```
public @Override void onBackPressed()
{
    if (doSomeThingOnBackPressed) {
        // do some stuff
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: So, I can not handle it in the ViewGroup, only in Activity?